# I had a problem with my sql program with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create database MALL; 
use MALL;

create table customer (
    customer_id int not null,
    name varchar (20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    registration_date date,
    primary key (customer_id)
);

create table inventory (
    item_id int not null,
    item_name varchar(20), 
    cost int,
    primary key (item_id)
);

create table purchase (
    purchase_date date,
    purchase_count int, 
    customer_id int,
    item_name varchar(20),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id),
    foreign key (item_name) references inventory(item_name)
);
```

I get this error

> ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
> index for constraint 'purchase_ibfk_2' in the referenced table
> 'inventory'

Comment: The error code is very explicit (and accurate)

Comment: Purchase table should have an item_id column instead of the item_name column. And it should be the FK.

Comment: You want to have `item_id` in table `purchase`, and then create a FK on `item_id`. FKs related to PKs, not descriptive fields.

Comment: You need to [read the documentation first](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions): "*MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
create table purchase (
    ...
    foreign key (item_name) references inventory(item_name)
)
```

The column referenced by the foreign key needs a unique index: `inventory(item_name)` does not have that. I would simply recommend referencing the primary key of `inventory` rather than some other column:

```
create table purchase (
    purchase_date date,
    purchase_count int, 
    customer_id int,
    item_id int,
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id),
    foreign key (item_id) references inventory(item_id)
);
```

Comment: Unique is good, but not required to be. Without unique [it works too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af959af9c49ea0b1617fe37595ceab09).